Can Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets unload assets loaded from AssetBundle?
After reading the Unity documentation, I have learned that assets loaded from the Resources folders using Resources.Load* can be unloaded from RAM using Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets. However, I'm unsure if I can also unload assets loaded from AssetBundles using AssetBundle.Load by calling Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets. The description of Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets states that it "unloads assets that are not used." Therefore, if assets instances created or clone from AssetBundles become unused, can they be unloaded from RAM by using Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets?
If the answer is affirmative, the design seems somewhat unusual. Unity emphasizes the use of Resources folders, yet we are able to unload resources from other locations using Resources.unload* as well.

https://forum.unity.com/threads/resources-unloadunusedassets-cannot-unload-assets-without-any-references.1088116/
